# Python script for retrieving the number of Google hits of a query

Tags: python

How can I get the number of hits for a Google query using Python?

I have a list containing the titles of songs from The Beatles:

```
    songs = ["Love Me Do", "P. S. I Love You", "Please Please Me"]
```

And I would like to retrieve the number of Google hits when I search Google for:

```
    The Beatles Love Me Do
    The Beatles P. S. I Love You
    The Beatles Please Please Me
```

And store these hits into another list. So in the end I'd end up with:

```
    google_hits == [42400000, 2740000, 28200000]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the quick and dirty solution I implemented:

```
import urllib
import json

artist = "The Beatles"
songs = ["Love Me Do", "P. S. I Love You", "Please Please Me"]
query = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=%s"

google_hits = list()
for song in songs:
    results = urllib.urlopen(query % (artist + " " + song))
    json_res = json.loads(results.read())
    google_hits.append(int(json_res['responseData']['cursor']['estimatedResultCount']))

print google_hits
```

I'm using the open [Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/), which is **deprecated**, but provided that you get yourself an API key for the new [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview), the process should be similar. Also, a quick note about the `estimatedResultCount` from the documentation:

> .estimatedResultCount - supplies the estimated number of results that
>   match the current query. Note that this value will not necessarily
>   match the similar value thats visible on the Google.com search
>   properties.

Comment: When I use your code I get an error:

    TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Code works when I've tried it, but I would suggest you to try implement a similar solution using the non-depricated API. Do you get any response from the call to `urllib.urlopen(...)`?

Comment: Ok, now it seems to be working, but the number of hits retrieved is very different from the one I get when I actually search for it on Google...

Answer (score 0):

You may find xgoogle useful for writing this code: https://github.com/pkrumins/xgoogle

Here is some working code showing how to iterate over and count results of a search: [How to use xgoogle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227985/how-to-use-xgoogle)